# Function for checking dataset nulls?

Tags: c#, null, dataset

I have a C# application (WinForm) that gets some information into several DataSets. From the datasets I save the information to a few string and int variables. Sometimes the values are null.. SO I would like to make a function that checks for nulls before trying to store into variables so I won't get any errors.

So in short I would like to replace a code like this(presuming I already have 2 DataSets called "dataSet1" and "dataSet2"):

```
row1 = dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[0];
if(row1.IsNull("Department")) {errorMsg}
else if(row1.IsNull("Name")) {errorMsg}
else 
//run code


row2 = dataSet2.Tables[0].Rows[0];
if(row2.IsNull("Department")) {errorMsg}
else if(row2.IsNull("Name")) {errorMsg}
else 
//run code
```

to something more automated like:

```
//the function
bool NullChecker(string datasetName, int rowNr, string fieldName)
{ 
if(datasetName.Tables[0].Rows[rowNr].IsNull(fieldName)) return false;
  else return true;
}

//back in the code
string[] datasetNames; int[] rowNrs; string[] fieldNames;

for(int i=0; i<someLength; i++)
{ NullChecker(datasetNames[i], rowNrs[i], fieldNames[i]);}
```

Possible? Also do you think this might slow down my code?

Comment: if it is null, what do you want to do?

Comment: @Selman22 IF it's null I would probably update the database with a valid value

Comment: I'm confused by this question, it appears you've already answered it? I don't see how adding such a function would cause a significant performance decrease.

Comment: @JustinSkiles My problem is that I'm using too many lines of code.. ....um, I haven't tested the function.. You mean to say that it will work as I wrote it?

Comment: @Vantalk, you should test it out and see what happens. There is nothing wrong with creating a method to check for null values.

Comment: OMG.. ok, I thought it's just something stupid I came up just to explain and get some real help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extension method for null checking

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this DataSet dataSet, int rowNumber, string columnName)
    {
        return dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber].IsNull(columnName);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
dataSet1.IsNull(0, "column");
```

If you want to print error messages as well, just add a parameter `string errorMsg` and before you return from the method call, print a text passed through an argument, like as follows

```
public static bool IsNull(this DataSet dataSet, int rowNumber, string columnName, string errorMsg)
{
    if(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber].IsNull(columnName))
    {
        // print an error message using Console or MessageBox, or whatever you use
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
dataSet1.IsNull(0, "column", "error");
```

Comment: If I make this function static will that require some other elements in my code to become static as well? I had some issues with something like that.. sry, I'm still a little unknowing at the involvements of data types.

Comment: The code looks great for extending. After reading the code closer I understand that you can use a loop to cycle through a dataset, but you can't cycle through an array on DataSets, unless I'm missing something.. Still, great piece of code. Marked as useful!

Comment: First, this may look like a static thing, but it's an extension method. It expands an existing class, `DataSet` in this case, in the way that it looks like the method is part of the class even if it's not. Second, sure you can cycle through an array of datasets. `for (...) { datasets[i].IsNull(...) }` If you think that my answer solves your question, mark it with a green mark under the scoring, that's the proper way.

Comment: You are right. I was too tired to realize that cycling the array is actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the code is good enough, with a small edit, need to replace the string array datasetName with a Database[] array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (dataSet1 != null && dataSet1.Tables.Count > 0)
```

----`further do actions`